# Setting the startDate on Datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to create a calendar using bootstrap datepicker that allows users to select a day starting 24 hours from today.  I saw this question posted on SO before but when I try the solution suggested it is not working for me.  The calendar works, but it still allows the user to select dates in the past:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-group date" id="dp3" data-date="" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
        <input class="form-control" name="schedule_pickup_date" type="text" value="">
        <span class="input-group-addon btn-primary" style="background-color: #0590e3;">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-1x white"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#dp3').datepicker({ 
            startDate: '+1d'
        });
    });
</script>
```

For some reason it looks like I am unable to set any options withing the $('#dp3').datepicker() function.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4xxP/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting startDate, but not [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate).

```
minDate: '+1d'
```

You are calling datepicker on wrong element though, change your code to this:

```
$('input[name="schedule_pickup_date"]').datepicker({
    startDate: '+1d',
    minDate: '+1d'
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NNC8S/)

Comment: just changed it and same thing... for some reason the code does not seem to recognize any of the options I set inside $('#dp3').datepicker({})

Comment: I updated my answer. Also, make sure you are including jQuery, and jQuery UI

Comment: still not working.  The jQuery is included, the calendar works except for not allowing to select days in the past - Here is the Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/X4xxP/

Comment: Ok, problem seems to be inside the bootstrap-datepicker.js library, if I remove it in the jsfiddle it works, however if I remove it from my code it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "startDate", try with "defaultDate".

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                disabledDates: [
                    moment("12/25/2013"),
                    new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                    "11/22/2013 00:53"
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

References: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/